# How would the Sun prove its self-awareness?

Tags: communication, stars

I am writing a short story in which the Sun becomes self -ware. It sends a signal out to communicate and we receive it. We think it's an alien entity. How can sun prove that the message is from sun? We can trace it back to sun but we will probably think that some species lives there.

**Now I have two questions.**

**First, what sort of message can sun send?** It cannot be a language but can be a low bandwidth frequency or something.

**Secondly, how will it prove that message is from sun?** I thought maybe it can move itself but that would create environmental issues. It cannot also heat up or down. But maybe it can not shine for one day or two? Would that create any issues for human beings?

Comment: You have 4 different questions here, which one would you like us to answer?

Comment: @JohnP What would be the mode of communication? And how will it prove that it is sun?

Comment: You might want to do a bit of research.  "It cannot also heat up or down.  But maybe it can not shine for one day or two?" Are you aware that the heat of the sun is the thing that causes it to shine?  Also, "what sort of message can the sun send" is a tricky start: messages are almost always thought of in terms of language.  If it isn't in terms of language, its usually not called a message.  At best it's called an emission.

Comment: How would it recognize us as other sentient beings, and mistake Earth itself for the sentience tranmissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that once it becomes self aware, it is possible for the sun to control itself - including solar flares.

1) By creating solar flares that last for different periods of time, the sun would be able to send out something like a "morse code" signal that humans would be able to record. I also remember seeing a movie where aliens communicated through humans via pulses representing prime numbers. This is also possible using the same "solar flare" method.

The effects of solar flares regarding damage, etc can be seen through a quick Google search or on sites like this one http://hesperia.gsfc.nasa.gov/sftheory/spaceweather.htm - essentially, Earth shouldn't take much damage since our magnetic fields protect us.

2) It's not exactly possible to prove it. It's not like the sun can just come to earth and say "Hey guys, i'm self aware now lols". However, it is possible for us to come to a conclusion with fairly high certainty that the sun is self aware - if the sun were self aware and the sun were communicating with us, all we'd have to do is to record the flare breakouts and convert them to something we understand. Or, if the sun were smart enough/able to, it could read signals that we send to the sun via pulses, the same way we would read the suns signals.

Comment: Can you control your body producing methane gas? Can you control how much your body sweats in the sun?

Comment: You can do more exercise thus increasing sweat amount.

You can eat more foods that make you fart.

The key assumption here is that the sun is able to control it's outer layer at the very least, not unlike how we can control our limbs. In a sense, a solar flare is more like the sun snapped his fingers.

Comment: You can do more exercise, yes, but the amount you actually sweat is out of your control. And yes, you can eat more gas producing foods, but you can't control how much you actually produce. Unless you radically change the structure of the sun, it wouldn't be able to control it's emanations any more than a human can.

Comment: We don't know if it suddenly becomes self aware or if it becomes self aware over time, possibly gaining said control. Note that this answer is completely based on the assumption that it can control itself. I'm just gonna handwave how it does that.

Comment: @JohnP Maybe I can't control the production of methane gas, but I do have some control over the *release* of that gas.

Comment: @KSmarts - Only marginally. The anal spincter is semi-smooth muscle, so you would have to actively control it. Continued hold would eventually result in loss of that control, or as soon as you stopped concentrating on it. Since you all seem so focused on that, the sun becoming self aware and suddenly controlling flares is akin to a human becoming self aware and controlling hair growth. Doesn't happen, unless as aify says, you do a *lot* of handwaving. But we all thank you for your pedanticism.